# Is it an anti-pattern in Python to define a module-level constant variable that's a string concatenation of other constant variables?

Tags: python

At a module level, is MY_VAR_C an anti-pattern in Python 3.8+?

```
MY_VAR_A = "my_var_a"
MY_VAR_B = "my_var_b"
MY_VAR_C: str = MY_VAR_A + MY_VAR_B
```

Comment: I won't say so https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/string.py#L32

Comment: Opinionated. What are your actual concerns?

Comment: @TedKleinBergman why does that example not use capital case?

Comment: Depends: do you use `MY_VAR_A` and `MY_VAR_B` for anything other than defining `MY_VAR_C`?

Comment: @user1008636 What do you mean? It does use capitals in its name.

Comment: Yes, it's fine (my **opinion**, so not a good StackOverflow question). Also, If `MY_VAR_A` and `MY_VAR_B` are only used for `MY_VAR_C` or only in **that file** and nowhere else, then they should be named `_MY_VAR_A` and `_MY_VAR_B` with [leading underscores to indicate that it's sort of "private"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1301346/1431750). Then readers (other coders) know to not use `A` and `B` in their code or imports, only to use `C`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is cheap and only executes once. So if it makes it easier to read it is a good trade off.